# How can i check if multiple variables equel to one thing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example

```
a=1
b=1
c=1

if ?:
    print("all of the variables are equal to 1")
```

So i want to only get an output when all of the variables are equel to 1, how do i do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if a == b == c == 1: